Embedding in projective groups
Let $G$ be a group generated by a permutation of degree $n=2^k$ consisting (including cycles of length 1)

of a single cycle

of two cycles of equal length


I'm interested in group $\langle G,h\rangle$, where $h$ is some permutation such that $\langle G,h\rangle$ is at least 2-transitive. Using some classification theorems there are only two variants for $\langle G,h\rangle$ in both cases: it either contains $A_n$ or $n=\frac{q^m-1}{q-1}$ and $PSL_m(q) \leq G \leq P \Gamma L_m(q)$ for some prime number $q$. What are the simplest means to distinguish these two cases? ( maybe, number of fixed points of $h$ or something like that). I would appreciate any help.

Do you mean a permutation of degree $n$ rather than $2^n$ in the first line?

@DerekHolt My bad, I meant $n=2^k$

I can't think of any way of using the extra information you have about the cycle structure of the generator of $G$ to help distinguish between the two cases. I can only advise that you use a software system such as GAP or Magma, which could answer the question very quickly for reasonably large values of $n$. Note that there are very fast Monte-Carlo algorithms for recognising when a subgroup of $S_n$ is equal to $A_n$ or $S_n$, so they could be used to answer the question very fast indeed, but with a very small chance of a wrong answer.
